# Validation on auto-populated field in a form in not working - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I have a form which has validation set up for all of the fields. For the validation I check if each input value is `required`, has the required `max length` and `min length`.  Once complete I do a final check to see if the whole form is valid.

The above validations work for the fields where the user physically types into the input field (which is how the tutorial I was following said to do it). However I amended the `Country` input field and the `Email` input field so that they were pre-filled. `Country` contains a default string of `England,UK` and the email field is pre-filled with the email that the user filled in when signing up from the state `this.props.email`. Now my form only returns as **valid** if I type something into those two fields next to the pre-filled data..after many hours of debugging I cannot see why...

See code below:

```
state = {
    orderForm: {
      name: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Your Name"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true 
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      postCode: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "PostCode"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 5,
          maxLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      country: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Country"
        },
        value: "England, UK",
        validation: {
          required: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      email: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Your E-Mail"
        },
        value: this.props.email,
        validation: {
          required: true
        },
        valid: false
    },
    formIsValid: false
  };
```

````
    inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
        const updatedOrderForm = {
          ...this.state.orderForm 
        };
        const updatedFormElement = {
      ...updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier] 
      };
    updatedFormElement.value = event.target.value; 
    updatedFormElement.valid = checkValidity(
      updatedFormElement.value,
      updatedFormElement.validation
    );

    updatedFormElement.touched = true; // ensures that the user types something in the input field
    updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier] = updatedFormElement; 


    let formIsValid = true;
    for (let inputIdentifier in updatedOrderForm) {
      formIsValid = updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid;
    }

    this.setState({ orderForm: updatedOrderForm, formIsValid: formIsValid });
  };

  render() {

    const formElementsArray = [];
    for (let key in this.state.orderForm) {
      formElementsArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.orderForm[key]
      });

    }
    let form = (
      <form>
        {formElementsArray.map(formElement => {
          return (
            <Input
              inputtype={formElement.config.elementType}
              key={formElement.id}
              elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
              elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
              value={formElement.config.value}
              invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
              shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
              touched={formElement.config.touched}
              changed={event =>
                this.inputChangedHandler(
                  event,
                  formElement.id,
                  formElement.config.value
                )
              }
            />
          );
        })}
        <Button
          clicked={this.orderHandler}
          btnType="Success"
          disabled={!this.state.formIsValid}
        >
          PLACE ORDER HERE
        </Button>
      </form>
    );```

  validation function
````

```
export const checkValidity = (value, validation) => {
  let isValid = true;

  if (validation.required) {
    isValid = value.trim() !== "" && isValid;
  }
  if (validation.minLength) {
    isValid = value.length >= validation.minLength && isValid;
  }

  if (validation.maxLength) {
    isValid = value.length <= validation.maxLength && isValid;
  }
 return isValid;
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume since you initially set `country` to false in `state.orderForm.country`, it will remain false unless changes are made.

```
country: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Country"
        },
        value: "England, UK",
        validation: {
          required: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      }
```

Since country already has a placeholder for 'England, UK' - and you consider that a valid submission, then change valid to true, as seen below. Your `checkValidity` function should cover you if the user enters invalid data.

```
country: {
            elementType: "input",
            elementConfig: {
              type: "text",
              placeholder: "Country"
            },
            value: "England, UK",
            validation: {
              required: true
            },
            valid: true,
            touched: false
          }
```

Also, you can probably shorten the `checkValidity` function to something roughly like below:

```
export const checkValidity = (value, validation) => {
  if (
    value.trim() !== ""
    && value.length >= validation.minLength
    && value.length <= validation.maxLength
  ) {
    return true
  }
  return false
 }
```

Comment: yes that works!! I will update my function too. For the email I need to do the same thing right? However the input will not always be pre populated so is this correct? :                                                                                                    ```email: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Your E-Mail"
        },
        value: this.props.email,
        validation: {
          required: true
        },
        valid: this.props.email ? true : false,
        touched: false
      }, ```

Comment: Yep, you'll also want to set a default `or` statement for `value: this.props.email`. See below:
`email: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Your E-Mail"
        },
        value: this.props.email || '',
        validation: true,
        valid: {
          this.props.email 
          ? true
          : false
        }
    }`